# Why my method is returning the result in Boolean?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following method which returns either `true` or `false` but I do not understand why.

```
public bool Check(string s)
{
    return s.Length == 8 && s.Count(Char.IsUpper) == 1 && s.Any(Char.IsDigit);
}
```

Please help me understand.

Comment: I've though only with return true or false you could get the bool result.

Comment: No, e.g. every comparison like that with `==` yields a bool value.

Comment: means "string exactly eight characters long, from these exactly one uppercase digit and at least one numeric digit"

Comment: return `true` if `s` has `Length` of `8`, has exactly one `Upper` case letter, and has at *least* one `digit`; side note: `Check` will **crash** on `s == null`; amendment: `return s != null && s.Length == 8 ...`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: I think that should be the answer.

Comment: @KlausGütter Thank you thats  also the answer I wanted to see.

Comment: What did you find hard to read? Equality comparer [`==`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators#equality-operator-)? The Logic operator [`&&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-)? Will `inputString.Count(chr =>Char.IsUpper(chr) )` be more understand able? Or did you need help on [`Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.count)?

Comment: @xdtTransform or maybe `s.Count(Char.IsUpper)`?

Comment: My best advice is to learn about The F1 and F12 key on your keyboard. Click in a function name, If you want to see it's definition press F12. And F1 to open the MSDN at the right page

Comment: @xdtTransform I dont get how can s.Count return true or false

Comment: What is the result you would have expected? Maybe we can explain it to you better...

Comment: "I dont get how can s.Count return true or false " it cannot, the entire expression is a comparison with a number: `s.Count(Char.IsUpper) == 1` the comparison returns either `true` or `false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code amended (it will crash on `s == null`) and commented:

```
public bool Check(string s)
{
    return                           // return true if and only if 
      s != null &&                   // s is not null and
      s.Length == 8 &&               // s has Length of 8 and
      s.Count(Char.IsUpper) == 1 &&  // s has exactly 1 Upper case letter and
      s.Any(Char.IsDigit);           // s has at least one digit 
}
```

Comment: May I know how does it return bool, because we dont have e.g. return true...

Comment: @plasma each line in the expression above returns a boolean result. I.e. `s != null` is a question: "is `s` null?" and the answer to that is either yes or no (true/false). The same logic applies to the other lines.

Answer (score 2):

You should read it like:

```
public bool Check(string s)
{
    // It would be worth to check for null
    if(s == null)
       throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(s));

    // because of the && all criteria must be true
    return 
        s.Length == 8                  // is the length 8?
        && s.Count(Char.IsUpper) == 1  // the must be one uppercase character? (the trick is to execute the IsUpper for each character)
        && s.Any(Char.IsDigit);        // Does it contain any digit? (same here)
}
```

Instead of using `string s`, you should give it better names, like `string password`. Same for the method name... `CheckPasswordConstraints`

Answer (score 2):

In your Check(string s) method you are check below three conditions.

1. `s.Length == 8` :

   - In this condition *equality operator* is used to check condition.
   - This condition will return `true` if s.Length is 8 otherwise `false`
2. `s.Count(Char.IsUpper) == 1` :

   - In this condition, again *equality operator* is used to check condition, but with `.Count()`.
   - if string s contains exact 1 upper case letter then it will return true otherwise false.
3. `s.Any(Char.IsDigit):`

   - `Linq .Any()` returns boolean `true`, if string contains atleast one digit.

&& operator to combine three different conditions,

> && returns true if all conditions are true. && returns false if any of
>   the condition is false

```
true && true && true => true

false && true && true => false
```

Answer (score 0):

`s.Count` and `s.Any` are methods, which counts (or signals if there are any elements in collection), with regard to method passed as an argument, which has to accept element of a colletion as a parameter and return true.

Since `string` is collection of `char`s, you can use `Any` and `Count`.

`Char.IsDigit` and `Char.IsUpper` are just methods of signeature:

```
bool MethodName(char c);
```

so they can be used in LINQ methods.

So, to sum up:

`Count(Char.IsUpper)` - counts upper characters

`Any(Char.IsDigit)` - signals, if we have at least one digit in string.

Comment: this does not really explain how it comes about that the result is a boolean

Comment: @MongZhu Yea that's exactly what I want to know but i think answer about he said every comparing with ```==``` returns boolean.

Comment: @plasma that is about right. But not only `==` returns a `bool`. You should read the documentation on [logical operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators). Every logical operator returns a `bool`. This link should be in at least one of the answers IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You are right not to understand this method, because the method name "Check" is not descriptive enough.  Check what exactly?  The method name should indicate what it is checking, or at the very least have comments which explain why and what it's doing.

Either way, the method is checking that the provided string:

- Is 8 characters long
- Has exactly one uppercase character
- Has at least one digit

Answer (score 0):

This method has 3 conditions:

- `s.Length == 8`
  this checks whether the length of string is exactly 8 or not.
- `s.Count(Char.IsUpper) == 1`
  this checks whether the total number of upper case letters in string is exactly equal to 1.
  Here an overload of `Count` is being used which expects a predicate `Count<TSource> (Func<TSource,bool> predicate)` and `Char.IsUpper` is the predicate which is being passed.
  Refference:
  [Count(predicate)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__)
  [Char.IsUpper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isupper?view=netframework-4.8#System_Char_IsUpper_System_Char_)
- `s.Any(Char.IsDigit)` this checks whether is there any digit in the string or not. Reference:
  [Char.IsDigit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=netframework-4.8#System_Char_IsDigit_System_Char_)

So, when all of these conditions are true , the `Check` method would return true.